# How to wait for async tasks to finish before moving to next lines?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, retrofit2

I would like my `fetchJson` statements (in the loop) to finish before moving onto `view.showFavouritePlaces(favouritePlaces)`.

Is there something I can wrap around the for loop to make it finish executing?

```
private var favouritePlaces: MutableList<Place> = mutableListOf()


init {

    // Populate List
    for(index in 0 until favPlaceStrings.size) {
        fetchJson(favPlaceStrings.elementAt(index))
    }

    // Display RecyclerView with updated info
    view.showFavouritePlaces(favouritePlaces)

}

…

override fun fetchJson(placeName: String) {

    ...

    call.enqueue(object: Callback<Place> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Place>?, t: Throwable?) {
            ...
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Place>?, response: Response<Place>?) {

            if(response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                val place: Place = response.body()!!

                println(place.toString())

                favouritePlaces.add(place)
            }
    }
})

}
```

Comment: Call view.showFavouritePlaces(favouritePlaces) in the onResponse method

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is to wrap your loop inside an `AsyncTask` and convert your retrofit call to synchronous. In the `onPostExecute`, you can perform the view setup.

If you are familiar with RxJava, there is an RxJava2CallAdapter for retrofit that converts the return type to observables, and process them as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Handle your next line in `onFailure` or `onResponse`

For example:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<Place>?, response: Response<Place>?) {

        if(response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            val place: Place = response.body()!!

            println(place.toString())

            favouritePlaces.add(place)

            view.showFavouritePlaces(favouritePlaces) // <== Put it here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know `Kotlin` but in `Java` yout can do this by this way if you are using `AsyncTask`

```
    String jsonData = new AsyncTask(url).execute().get();
```